# How to close tab by clicking on itself and not only by opening a new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have a set of 3 tabs. At any given time, only 1 tab can be opened because the other 2 close when I open one of them. So far so good. However I can't manage to close the open tab by clicking on it. Nothing happens when an already open tab is clicked on. It only closes if another tab is opened. My question is: how can I adjust this piece of code so that the open tab can be closed by clicking on itself? Here is the code:

```
$('.collapsible-trigger').on('click', function() {
    var x = $('.collapsible-trigger-btn--borders').hasClass('is-open') 
    var x = $('.collapsible-content--all').hasClass('is-open');
    if (x) {
        $('.collapsible-trigger-btn--borders').attr('aria-expanded','false');
        $('.collapsible-trigger-btn--borders').removeClass('is-open');
        $('.collapsible-content--all').removeClass('is-open');
        $('.collapsible-content--all').css("height","0px");
    }
});
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the portion of your markup which defines your tabs.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Why do you declare and define the same variable twice in a row ? Do you want both conditions to apply or either one ?

Comment: A wild guess: Some other js handler code listens to the `click` event on a tab and opens that tab. This code is executed _after_ the excerpt you have shown. If you prefer a sound answer over guesswork in comments, please provide all relevant detail, first of all the markup and the event binding code.